# How to convert absolute path to relative path?

Tags: linux, shell, filenames

How do I use a command to convert an absolute path to a path relative to the current working directory?

Comment: so we should assume that the absolute path in-hand refers to the current directory or a subdirectory thereof? In what form is the absolute path: a variable? a line in a file? stdin? other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
realpath --relative-to=. /absolute/path
```

More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory-using-bash).

Comment: I would also mention `realpath`'s `-s` option, which prevents the expansion of symbolic links. Useful if the argument is a symlink and you don't want it resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of 'rolling your own"

```
here=/dir1
there=/dir1/dir4/dir5/my.file
root=""
if [ ! -z $(grep "^$here" <<<$there) ]; then
    root="./"
else while [ -z $(grep  "^$here" <<<$there) ]; do
    here=${here%/*}
    root=${root}../
    done
fi
echo $root$(sed "s|^$here/||g" <<<$there)

./dir4/dir5/my.file
```

and for

```
here=/dir1/dir2/dir3

../../dir4/dir5/my.file
```